# How to append something in a specific element?

Tags: javascript

How do I append the created element in a specific element?

```
  container = document.createElement( 'div' );
  document.body.appendChild( container );
```

Comment: You replace `document.body` with one of the many methods there are to find specific elements. How you do that depends on the specific element.

Comment: @ArthurS. do you need help with something else? Will you please accept an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this...

`document.getElementById('specific_ele').appendChild(container);`

Answer (score 1):

This code will append "container" in the body element. To append it in another element, you have to select it at first. So you can use `getElementById()` (as WhiteHat proposed) or [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to find the element. Then you can use `appendChild()` for append tag into found tag.